# New-ADUser with -L property set

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to use powershell New-ADUser with the parameter `-L`.
This works when the length of the `-L` parameter value is less or equal to 15 chars.
I get an error when length > 15 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `-L` is the LDAP display name of `-City` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps)

If I change the property name from `-L` to `-City`, I can add content with length greater than 15 chars and the content ends up in the attribute `l`.